# future posts in pagination

Tags: wordpress, pagination, timber

My wordpress-timber pagination ignores future posts. How do I fix that?

I have custom post type running with the post_status publish and future. This works well while listing those posts on one page. But when I try to set a simple pagination in my theme, it will ignore the future posts.

I think the way wordpress handles permalinks of future posts diffrent to regular posts could be part of the solution.

Now I’m looking for a way to tell wordpress to ignore the concept of publish vs. future. What would you try and how?

```
$context['wechselausstellung'] = Timber::get_posts('post_type=wechselausstellung&post_status=publish,future');
```

```
  {% if post.prev %}
    <a href="{{ post.prev.link }}"><i class="pfeil">←</i>zurück</a>
  {% endif %}
  {% if post.next %}
    | <a href="{{ post.next.link }}" class="toplink__vor">vor<i class="pfeil">→</i></a>
  {% endif %}
```

Comment: Do you use this on an archive page or in a singular template?

Comment: … on a single. sorry for not mentioning.